# "Supported by" or "Sponsored by"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

This problem came to my mind when I saw ads on YT. In my native language (those two words are derived from English and have exactly the same spellings), we might use both (equally) to say:

> The video is supported/sponsored by X.

**X** is a product and could be anything like shampoo, drinks, food, etc. I believe those two have different meaning.

The word **support** have 6 senses according to CALD i.e. encourage, help, provide, stop from falling, prove, and accept. However, CALD also defines the verb **sponsor** to support a person, organization, or activity by giving money, encouragement, or other help. It's perplexing and paradoxical.

Are these terms interchangeable?

My reason I'm asking this question is because someone corrected me when I commented this video is *supported by* X and suggested *sponsored by* instead. From here, I'm questioning the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you describe (YT video sponsorship/support) they have different connotations.

"Sponsored by" suggests that the entity doing the sponsoring has paid the full cost. They are primarily responsible.

"Supported by" suggests less involvement. They approve, may have provided some financial support, but are not as directly involved.

Comment: I disagree, as a native English speaker. I think "sponsored by" and "supported by" can be used more or less interchangeably, in the context of YouTube videos -- both indicate "financial support," generally speaking. I don't associate sponsorship with "paid the full cost" as you say. Sponsorship may have a *slightly* stronger connotation of financial support, if anything, but it is very slight.

Comment: @BrandonDuffany Fair points. I hear "sponsored" as not just a little stronger than "supported" but we can disagree.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, you have support/sponsorship on one YouTube video.

Differences:

- "Sponsored by" would be more like a bigger company paying you for the video, and they're usually responsible for the video. Let's say that somebody is filming a video for the sponsored company, and the sponsored company also uses it.
- "Supported by" doesn't indicate that it has to be financial support, it usually is, but it would be some entity is indirectly involved and maybe provided a little financial support, but might not be responsible for the causes of the video.

Even though they might have subtle differences. I do still agree that they could be interchangeable.

But maybe "sponsored" indicates more involvement than "supported".